# Validate U.S. Phone Numbers Only

Tags: php, validation, preg-replace, preg-match, phone-number

I am presently building a website, in PHP, that users will be able to interact with via SMS messaging.  Consequently, I need to store their phone numbers in my database.  Since I am only allowing SMS interactions in the U.S. right now, I need to check that the submitted phone numbers conform to the U.S. format.  Generally, this means a few things: `1` must be the first number, the area code must not begin with `0` or `1`, and the string without the leading `1` must be 10 digits (3 digit area code plus 7 digit number).

Despite all of these requirements, I want users to feel free to enter their number in whatever format they prefer without causing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring non-digits is the first step.  The leading 1 is not required by all telephone companies, particularly near New Jersey.  Dialing it there causes an error or a wrong number.

The area code cannot be [2-9]11 nor [2-9]9[0-9].  Area codes with a 9 as the center digit are reserved for an as-yet-undecided scheme to address area code exhaustion.

Exchanges also cannot begin with a 0 or 1, nor can they be [2-9]11.

---

These restrictions are expressed with this code:

```
$mobile = preg_replace ('/\D/', '', $trimmed['mobile']);

if ($mobile[0] == '1') $mobile = substr ($mobile, 1);  // remove prefix

$invalid = strlen ($mobile) != 10  ||
           preg_match ('/^1/',      $mobile) ||  // ac start with 1
           preg_match ('/^.11/',    $mobile) ||  // telco services
           preg_match ('/^...1/',   $mobile) ||  // exchange start with 1
           preg_match ('/^....11/', $mobile) ||  // exchange services
           preg_match ('/^.9/',     $mobile);    // ac center digit 9
```

Comment: that is a valid point.  I'm not good enough with regex to write an efficient statement to rule out `[x]11` area codes.  If you can do that, I'll gladly credit you with the answer.

Comment: @David:  I've added code to do it, but note that it identifies invalid numbers; everything not signaled as invalid should be valid.

Comment: I have never seen anyone use multiple preg_match and OR statements as you have. Is this somehow more efficient than a single regex?

Comment: @David:  It is more efficient in human terms:  it says exactly what it needs to, it is easy to understand and validate.  If there is a way to combine them into fewer matches I don't immediately see it.

Answer (score 0):

After learning what I could from searching and scouring, I could not find a U.S. only method.  So, here is what I devised:

First, to allow for any input format, use `preg_replace` to remove all non-digit characters. [Users can use whatever hyphens or slashes they want, but they are of no use to me.]

```
$mobile = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $trimmed['mobile']);
```

With just a pure string of digits to work with, eliminate any leading `1`s — this takes care of any instance where the user included the leading 1 or where they started the area code with `1`.  [If valid, this should always leave me with a `10` digit string.]

```
$mobiletrim = ltrim($mobile, '1');
```

Next, regex checks that the trimmed phone number is precisely `10` digits long and does not begin with either a `0` or a `1`.

```
    if (preg_match ('/^[2-9]\d{9}$/', $mobiletrim) || empty($trimmed['mobile'])) {
        $mp = TRUE;
        if (!empty($trimmed['mobile'])) { $mobiletrim = "1" . $mobiletrim; }
    } else {
        $profile_errors[] = "Please enter a valid U.S. phone number.";
    }
if ($mp) { //Store Phone Number in db }
```

The final step, which you can see above, was to add the leading `1` before storing the valid number in the db, provided that the user did not submit an empty phone field, which they would do if they didn't want their number stored.

---

Technically, this will validate all NANP numbers.  The only way to narrow it down from NANP to U.S. exclusively would be to verify that a U.S. area code was used by parsing through a list of current U.S. area codes.

Comment: @Sammitch, when you go to the Ask Question form, you have the option of Answering it at the same time.  That is a feature of the StackExchange sites, to be used when people want to share their knowledge but a fitting question does not exist.
    
Down-voting because I shared my knowledge in accordance with StackExchange policies and design makes no sense at all.